How to link table panels in R Shiny Dashboard using datatable to filter data in table 2 based on click in table 1?
Is it possible to program a dashboard with the same functionality as in this example, but instead of using reactable, using the DT (DataTable) package?
Requirement: Jump to Table 2 for showing detailed information after click in Table 1. The counting of totals in the footer as shown in the above mentioned question is not necessary.
Are there any comparative studies on which package is better suited for displaying large datasets?
This is an example without the functionality for which I am asking.
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

d1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Frank", "Emma", "Kurt", "Johanna", "Anna", "Ben", "Chris", "David", "Eva", "Felix", "Gina", "Hannah", "Iris", "Jack", "Karen", "Leo", "Mia", "Nina", "Omar", "Paul"),
  team = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  score = c(12, 15, 13, 13, 14, 11, 10, 16, 9, 8, 17, 14, 12, 13, 15, 16, 11, 10, 9, 8)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  name = c(
    "Frank", "Frank", "Frank",
    "Emma", "Emma", "Emma",
    "Kurt", "Kurt", "Kurt",
    "Johanna", "Johanna", "Johanna",
    "Anna", "Anna", "Anna",
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben",
    "Chris", "Chris", "Chris",
    "David", "David", "David",
    "Eva", "Eva", "Eva",
    "Felix", "Felix", "Felix",
    "Gina", "Gina", "Gina",
    "Hannah", "Hannah", "Hannah",
    "Iris", "Iris", "Iris",
    "Jack", "Jack", "Jack",
    "Karen", "Karen", "Karen",
    "Leo", "Leo", "Leo",
    "Mia", "Mia", "Mia",
    "Nina", "Nina", "Nina",
    "Omar", "Omar", "Omar",
    "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"
  ),
  match = c(
    1, 2, 3,  # Frank
    1, 2, 3,  # Emma
    1, 2, 3,  # Kurt
    1, 2, 3,  # Johanna
    1, 2, 3,  # Anna
    1, 2, 3,  # Ben
    1, 2, 3,  # Chris
    1, 2, 3,  # David
    1, 2, 3,  # Eva
    1, 2, 3,  # Felix
    1, 2, 3,  # Gina
    1, 2, 3,  # Hannah
    1, 2, 3,  # Iris
    1, 2, 3,  # Jack
    1, 2, 3,  # Karen
    1, 2, 3,  # Leo
    1, 2, 3,  # Mia
    1, 2, 3,  # Nina
    1, 2, 3,  # Omar
    1, 2, 3   # Paul
  ),
  score = c(
    4, 4, 4,  # Frank (12)
    5, 5, 5,  # Emma (15)
    4, 4, 5,  # Kurt (13)
    4, 4, 5,  # Johanna (13)
    5, 4, 5,  # Anna (14)
    4, 4, 3,  # Ben (11)
    4, 3, 3,  # Chris (10)
    6, 5, 5,  # David (16)
    3, 3, 3,  # Eva (9)
    3, 3, 2,  # Felix (8)
    6, 6, 5,  # Gina (17)
    5, 5, 4,  # Hannah (14)
    4, 4, 4,  # Iris (12)
    4, 4, 5,  # Jack (13)
    5, 5, 5,  # Karen (15)
    6, 5, 5,  # Leo (16)
    4, 4, 3,  # Mia (11)
    4, 3, 3,  # Nina (10)
    3, 3, 3,  # Omar (9)
    3, 3, 2   # Paul (8)
  )
)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Table 1", tabName = "table1", icon = icon("table")),
      menuItem("Table 2", tabName = "table2", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "table1",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    title = "Table 1",
                    dataTableOutput("table1"))
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "table2",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    title = "Table 2",
                    dataTableOutput("table2"))
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      d1,
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = FALSE,
      selection = "none",
      filter="top"
    )
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      d2,
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = FALSE,
      selection = "none",
      filter="top"
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Here is a DT variant of the reactable solution which uses dataTableProxy in combination with updateSearch() to modify the table on the second tab.

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

d1 <- data.frame(
  name = c("Frank", "Emma", "Kurt", "Johanna", "Anna", "Ben", "Chris", "David", "Eva", "Felix", "Gina", "Hannah", "Iris", "Jack", "Karen", "Leo", "Mia", "Nina", "Omar", "Paul"),
  team = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),
  score = c(12, 15, 13, 13, 14, 11, 10, 16, 9, 8, 17, 14, 12, 13, 15, 16, 11, 10, 9, 8)
)

d2 <- data.frame(
  name = c(
    "Frank", "Frank", "Frank",
    "Emma", "Emma", "Emma",
    "Kurt", "Kurt", "Kurt",
    "Johanna", "Johanna", "Johanna",
    "Anna", "Anna", "Anna",
    "Ben", "Ben", "Ben",
    "Chris", "Chris", "Chris",
    "David", "David", "David",
    "Eva", "Eva", "Eva",
    "Felix", "Felix", "Felix",
    "Gina", "Gina", "Gina",
    "Hannah", "Hannah", "Hannah",
    "Iris", "Iris", "Iris",
    "Jack", "Jack", "Jack",
    "Karen", "Karen", "Karen",
    "Leo", "Leo", "Leo",
    "Mia", "Mia", "Mia",
    "Nina", "Nina", "Nina",
    "Omar", "Omar", "Omar",
    "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"
  ),
  match = c(
    1, 2, 3,  # Frank
    1, 2, 3,  # Emma
    1, 2, 3,  # Kurt
    1, 2, 3,  # Johanna
    1, 2, 3,  # Anna
    1, 2, 3,  # Ben
    1, 2, 3,  # Chris
    1, 2, 3,  # David
    1, 2, 3,  # Eva
    1, 2, 3,  # Felix
    1, 2, 3,  # Gina
    1, 2, 3,  # Hannah
    1, 2, 3,  # Iris
    1, 2, 3,  # Jack
    1, 2, 3,  # Karen
    1, 2, 3,  # Leo
    1, 2, 3,  # Mia
    1, 2, 3,  # Nina
    1, 2, 3,  # Omar
    1, 2, 3   # Paul
  ),
  score = c(
    4, 4, 4,  # Frank (12)
    5, 5, 5,  # Emma (15)
    4, 4, 5,  # Kurt (13)
    4, 4, 5,  # Johanna (13)
    5, 4, 5,  # Anna (14)
    4, 4, 3,  # Ben (11)
    4, 3, 3,  # Chris (10)
    6, 5, 5,  # David (16)
    3, 3, 3,  # Eva (9)
    3, 3, 2,  # Felix (8)
    6, 6, 5,  # Gina (17)
    5, 5, 4,  # Hannah (14)
    4, 4, 4,  # Iris (12)
    4, 4, 5,  # Jack (13)
    5, 5, 5,  # Karen (15)
    6, 5, 5,  # Leo (16)
    4, 4, 3,  # Mia (11)
    4, 3, 3,  # Nina (10)
    3, 3, 3,  # Omar (9)
    3, 3, 2   # Paul (8)
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Test"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = "tabs",
      menuItem("Table 1", tabName = "table1", icon = icon("table")),
      menuItem("Table 2", tabName = "table2", icon = icon("table"))
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "table1",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    title = "Table 1",
                    DTOutput("table1"))
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "table2",
              fluidRow(
                box(width = 12,
                    title = "Table 2",
                    DTOutput("table2"))
              )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      d1,
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = FALSE,
      selection = "none",
      filter="top"
    ) |> 
      formatStyle(1, cursor='pointer')
  })
  
  output$table2 <- renderDT({
    datatable(
      d2,
      rownames = FALSE,
      editable = FALSE,
      selection = "none",
      filter="top"
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$table1_cell_clicked$value, {
    filterValues <- c(input$table1_cell_clicked$value, "", "")
    proxy |>
      updateSearch(keywords = list(columns = filterValues))
    
    updateTabItems(session, "tabs", "table2")
  })
  
  outputOptions(output, "table2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  proxy <- dataTableProxy('table2')
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Concerning the question regarding the comparative studies between reactable and DT I do not such studies, however, using both solutions you should be able to test them for large data sets and compare the performance. On my machine, I tested it using a data set which was derived by using rep(., 100000) on all columns of your data d1 and d2 and got a considerably fast result using DT, whereas reactable was very slow.

Thanks!!! The solution works wonderfully. I will compare both options (DT versus reactable) and will report my findings soon.
